# What's the difference between le magasin and la boutique?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, commerce

My textbook has a sentence which reads,

> Le samedi matin vers onze heures, j'adore retrouver mes amies pour visiter les magasins et les boutiques de notre centre-ville.
>
> On Saturday mornings, around eleven o'clock, I like getting together with my friends to visit the shops and boutiques in our downtown.

Is a boutique just a more upscale version of a magasin? Is it the same distinction that we have here in America between shops and boutiques?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[**Magasin**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/magasin)* has several meanings and is generic when referring to shops while *[**boutique**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boutique)* is more about small and often specialized shops.

Technically, the ***magasin*** is more the back-end storage area while the ***boutique*** is the front-end store on the street. The *magasin* of a shop is still sometimes called its *arrière-boutique*.

Note that these words come from foreign words both originally meaning "storage area":

- *Boutique* comes from the greek *ἀποθήκη* "apotheke" so *[boutiquier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boutiquier)* and *[apothicaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apothicaire)* are related.
- *Magasin* comes from the arabic *مَخَازِن‏* "makazin"

Comment: Je comprends. Merci!